# Java class inside the gradle build file fails

Tags: groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew, gradle-plugin

`leftShift` is deprecated in Gradle now.

I am trying to add a java class initialization inside the gradle build file like below:

```
task javaClassInGradleTask {

doLast {
    class Myclass {

       public void message() {

          System.out.println("this is message from java class");

       }

   }

   Myclass testObject = new Myclass();

   testObject.message();
 }
}
```

and I am trying to run the file:

```
gradle javaClassInGradleTask
```

My error result is below

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * Where:
>   Build file '/Users/folder/build.gradle' line: 3
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Could not compile build file '/Users/folder/build.gradle'.
>     startup failed:
>     build file '/Users/folder/build.gradle': 3: Class definition not expected here. Please define the class at an appropriate place or perhaps try using a block/Closure instead. at line: 3 column: 2. File: *BuildScript* @ line 3, column 2.
>         class Myclass {
>       ^
>
>   1 error
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 0s

But when I try to add the class using `leftShift` it works well.

Any idea to add class inside the gradle file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work for both `doLast` and `<<`. Try:

```
task javaClassInGradleTask {
  doLast {
    Myclass testObject = new Myclass()
    testObject.message();
  }
}

class Myclass {
  public void message() {
    System.out.println("this is message from java class");
  }
}
```